# Regarding message send in singnal R

Tags: asp.net, signalr, signalr-hub

Hello friends I have developed many to many chat application using signal R it is working perfectly fine.But i am getting one problem in developing one thing..that is typing message to  the reciever for example:- there are two user online user x and user y.now when user x is typing message..on user y window it should come.."user x is typing message.." but when i send this message to group it is getting displayed on both screen..I want to display it on reciever screen only

This is the code

```
public void Send(string message, string groupName, string Istypingmessage)
{
    if (Clients != null)
    {

        string[] words = message.Split(':');
        string trim = words[0].Trim();
        string imagetag = "<img width=\"32px\" height=\"32px\" src=\"userimages/" + trim + ".jpg" + "\"" + "></img> ";
        Clients.Group(groupName).addMessage(message, groupName, words[0], imagetag, Istypingmessage);


    }
}
```

where here typing message=0 means normal message and 1 means "user x is typing that message"
This is the key press event

```
 //keypress event of textbbox here..
        $(".ChatText").live('keyup', function () {
            if($(".ChatText").val().length > 0)
            {
               var messsage_typing=$("#hdnUserName").val() + " is typing...";
               var strGroupName = $(this).parent().attr('groupname');
                if (typeof strGroupName !== 'undefined' && strGroupName !== false)
                    chat.server.send($("#hdnUserName").val() + ' : ' + messsage_typing, $(this).parent().attr('groupname'),"1");

            }
        });
        //end of keypress
```

and this is add message code

```
  chat.client.addMessage = function (message, groupName,recievername,imagetag,Istypingmessage) {

            if ($('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').length == 0) {
                var chatWindow = $("#divChatWindow").clone(true);
                $(chatWindow).css('display', 'block');
                $(chatWindow).attr('groupname', groupName);

                $("#chatContainer").append(chatWindow);
                //buggy code do not delete..
                //remove all previous li
                $('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul li').remove();
                //replace header tag with new name
                $('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('a').html(recievername);
                $("#chatContainer").draggable();
                $("#chatContainer").css('cursor','move');
            }
            if(Istypingmessage=="0")
            {
                 var stringParts = message.split(":");
                 var username = stringParts[0];
                 var message = stringParts[1];
                 //this code is for continous message sent
                 var lastliusername=$('div[groupname=' + groupName + '] ul li').eq(-2).find('div.designnone').html();               
                 if(lastliusername!=null && $.trim(username)==$.trim(lastliusername))
                 {
                    $('div[groupname=' + groupName + '] ul li').eq(-2).find('div.designmessage').append("<span class='spansameuser'>" + message + "</span>");
                    //end of this code is for continous message sent
                 }
                 else 
                 {
                    $('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul').append("<li><div class='design'>" + imagetag + "</div><div class='designnone'> " + username + "</div><div class='designmessage'> " + message + " </div></li><li class='cleardivbetweenmsg'></li>");
                 }

             }
             else 
             {
                    $('div[groupname=' + groupName + ']').find('ul').append("<li><span>Hellos</span></li>");
             }
             $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages")[0].scrollHeight);
        };
```

How can i display typing message to my reciever instead of on both screens..please help me out..In short i want to send my message only to reciever of group not to sender of the group
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you want to send a message to all clients in a group except for the sender, you can use `Clients.OthersInGroup`:

```
 Clients.OthersInGroup(groupName).addMessage(/*...*/);
```

This is the equivalent to passing the sender's connection ID as a second parameter to `Clients.Group` making it an excluded connection ID.

```
 Clients.Group(groupName, Context.ConnectionId).addMessage(/*...*/);
```

The method signature for `Clients.Group` is: `public dynamic Group(string groupName, params string[] excludeConnectionIds)`.